# Multiplying columns by randbetween in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, random

I've got a table of real values that I'm trying to skew slightly for a demo table.

The table layout is effectively:

```
|id|purchased|shipped|delivered|
```

and I'm trying to multiply the right 3 columns by 85-115% so that the data still gives a reasonable representation of the original table, without giving away actual values.

In excel I'd do

```
=purchased*(randbetween(85,115)/100)
```

for each column, but I'm trying to do the same with SQL, so that each row is multiplied by a different random number within the range.

I'm fairly new to sql, and I'm trying to avoid exporting the entire table, randomising the values in Excel and re-importing the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rand()` with arithmetic:

```
select purchased * (0.85 + rand()*0.30)
from . . .
```

This does what the *question* asks for, which is increasing or decreasing by about 15%.  The code in Excel multiplies the value by about 100.

EDIT:

The update statement would be something like:

```
update table t
    set purchased = purchased * (0.85 + rand()*0.30)
```

As a final note:  this doesn't work exactly like the Excel version.  One reason is that this uses continuous values rather than integer values.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to multiply by 0.85 -01.15